# Change font color during CSV to HTML conversion if number value is greater than 100

Tags: html, bash, awk, sed

i have this **csv file** i successfully convert to html with the script below.

```
name,age
mike,109
sarah,25
```

**Conversion Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'BEGIN {
h[1] = "name"
h[2] = "age"
    FS=","
print "<!DOCTYPE html>" \
"<html>" \
"<head>" \
"<style>" \
"th { color:#f2f2f2; background-color: #73BD00;}th, td { text-align: left; padding: 8px; font-family: Arial;} {background-color: #f2f2f2;}" \
"th, td {  text-align: left; padding: 8px; }" \
"tr { background-color: #f2f2f2;}" \
"</style>" \
"</head>" \
"<body>" \
"<h2> DATA TITLE </h2>" \
"<table border-collapse=collapse  width=50%;> " \
}

#insert rows into table from file
{
print "<tr>"
#NF is a number of fields in each records

for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
{
#insert first row of file as header
if (NR==1){
print "<th>" h[i] "</th>"
} else
print "<td>" $i "</td>"
}
print "</tr>"
}

END {
print "</table>"
"</body>" \
"</html>"
}' file.csv > filex.html;
```

Now i'm trying to figure out how to use either Sed or Awk to change the font color if the age is greater than 100.

**What i've tried with SED:**

I could have easily used Sed after the conversion like this if the value was just a generic number but the value changes depending on the file. What i'm trying to do is to have the value change color to RED only IF its greater than 100 which i'm not sure on how to do or if it's even possible

```
sed 's/109/<font color="red">9<\/font>/g' finalx.html > filey.html
```

**What i've tried with AWK:**
i've tried to input this lines of codes into the conversion script in so many different ways  but nothing seems to work.

```
NR>1 {
  # Data rows
  print "<tr>"
  
  if( $i > 100 ) {
    color="#FF0000" #color code for RED
  }
  print "</tr>"
}
```

i even tried editing the csv file before converting hoping that if i put the html font tag in the csv file with my condition, the conversion will pick it up and come out the way i intend but even my use of awk is wrong, so i didn't get that far to even test it out

```
awk -F "[, ]+" '$2>100{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)$i="<font color="red">$i</font>"}1'
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

---

EDIT: here's the original code above formatted to be readable by `gawk -o-`:

```
BEGIN {
        h[1] = "name"
        h[2] = "age"
        FS = ","
        print "<!DOCTYPE html>" "<html>" "<head>" "<style>" "th { color:#f2f2f2; background-color: #73BD00;}th, td { text-align: left; padding: 8px; font-family: Arial;} {background-color: #f2f2f2;}" "th, td {  text-align: left; padding: 8px; }" "tr { background-color: #f2f2f2;}" "</style>" "</head>" "<body>" "<h2> DATA TITLE </h2>" "<table border-collapse=collapse  width=50%;> "
}

{
        print "<tr>"
        #NF is a number of fields in each records
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
                #insert first row of file as header
                if (NR == 1) {
                        print "<th>" h[i] "</th>"
                } else {
                        print "<td>" $i "</td>"
                }
        }
        print "</tr>"
}

#insert rows into table from file
END {
        print "</table>"
        "</body>" "</html>"
}
```

Comment: the `font` tag is for HTML4. With HTML5 you should use inline `style` or better, a CSS `class`.

Comment: Please format your code to be readable by using appropriate white space and indenting, etc., especially when posting on a forum and asking others to read/understand it so they can help you with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this snippet

```
awk -F "[, ]+" '$2>100{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)$i="<font color="red">$i</font>"}1'
```

you have unescaped `"` thus you will get

```
<font color=>$i</font>
```

where 2nd field is greater than 100, you need to escape `"` where there should mean literal `"` and concat strings with `$i` rather than use it inside string, i.e.

```
awk -F "[, ]+" '$2>100{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)$i="<font color=\"red\">"$i"</font>"}1'
```

However this will casue lines which do fullfill `$2>100` to be now space-separated and rest still comma-separated, to avoid this I suggest setting FS and OFS to comma, that is

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}$2>100{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)$i="<font color=\"red\">"$i"</font>"}1'
```

Comment: This theory worked thanks. 
Apparently setting those tags before the conversion produced the result i needed

Comment: @Daweo, clever ! Awk always has a shorter way of writing things.  I thought conditions were per-line only.   Works because `$i`  expands to `$2`, replacing the variable.   And `1` prints the data.    Just if someone wondered (and for myself).

Comment: `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","  ; cf=2 }  $2>100{ $cf="<font color='red'>"$cf"</font>" }  1  `    should also work, since the field to check is always 2.

Comment: @MyICQ while that would work if the script was stored in a file, it won't work when passed directly to awk as you can't include `'`s in `'`-delimited string in shell. `'red'` would need to be `\"red\"` or `\047red\047` to work portably.

Comment: @EdMorton that is correct, I missed  this fact. I can't edit the comment. Good point with the numbers if quotes are needed where they can't be placed. Could be useful in Windows command line.

Answer (score 1):

Not testet, but something along these lines in your Bash script:

```
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
{
#insert first row of file as header
if (NR==1){
     print "<th>" h[i] "</th>"
 } else
   # -- data field 1 should just print
   if (i == 1) {
     print "<td>" $i "</td>"
   }
   # -- next field should have special td tag if condition is met
   if (i == 2) {
       TDTAG = "<td>"
      if (h[i] > MAXVALUE) {
         TDTAG = "<td class='max'>"
        }
       print TDTAG $i "</td>"
    }
}
print "</tr>"
}
```

This way your data lines should be something along

```html
   <td>john</td><td class='max'>140</td>
   <td>mary</td><td>14</td>
```

**hint** : you can write a "wrapper" function in awk that wraps each field for you in correct `td` tags. Could improve readability.

Personally I would do this via a separate awk script, instead of inline in bash. But that's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

**tested `awk` solution**

I've taken the liberty of restructuring your initial `awk` script to replace the loops with `awk` `pattern`-`action` blocks which, in my view, simplifies the logic as `awk` is already an iterative process. (`awk` sends sequential `records`, in your case lines, through a process where `action`s can be applied to each of the collection of `fields`, in your case comma-separated data points.)

I've inserted a small `action` block before the main blocks which sets the value of a variable  named `colorclass` to either `'high'` or `'normal'` depending on value of `field` 2 (`$2`) of the current record:

```
{colorclass= ($2>100 ? "high" : "normal")}
```

Earlier, I modified your `style` declarations to add `css rules` for two new `classes`:

```
"td.normal {color: black}" \
"td.high {color: red}" \
```

Next, your main loops have been replaced with two `pattern`/`action` blocks, the first to render the `header` text, the second to render regular `tr` rows:

```
NR==1{print "\n<tr>\n  <th>"$1"</th>\n  <th>"$2"</th>\n</tr>\n"}
NR>1{print "<tr>\n  <td>"$1"</td>\n  <td class=\""colorclass"\">"$2"</td>\n</tr>\n"}
```

In each case, the `action` is only applied where the `pattern` is `true`. Thus, the first block is only used when `NR==1`, and the second `NR>1` is applied to all subsequent `records` (lines).

The second `action` block for regular table rows, inserts a `class attribute` with value either `normal` or `high` (as set in the initial pattern-less `action` block.

Here is the modified script. I tested it in Terminal on Mac, and viewed the table with firefox:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
h[1] = "name"
h[2] = "age"
    FS=","
print "<!DOCTYPE html>" \
"<html>" \
"<head>" \
"<style>" \
"th { color:#f2f2f2; background-color: #73BD00;}th, td { text-align: left; padding: 8px; font-family: Arial;} {background-color: #f2f2f2;}" \
"th, td {  text-align: left; padding: 8px; }" \
"tr { background-color: #f2f2f2;}" \
"td.normal {color: black}" \
"td.high {color: red}" \
"</style>" \
"</head>" \
"<body>" \
"<h2> DATA TITLE </h2>" \
"<table border-collapse=collapse  width=50%;> " \
}

{colorclass= ($2>100 ? "high" : "normal")}
NR==1{print "\n<tr>\n  <th>"$1"</th>\n  <th>"$2"</th>\n</tr>\n"}
NR>1{print "<tr>\n  <td>"$1"</td>\n  <td class=\""colorclass"\">"$2"</td>\n</tr>\n"}

END {
print "</table>"
"</body>" \
"</html>"
}' dataFile.csv > output.html;
```

Comment: this works in general but it doesn't allow the flexibility to modify the title header which was the part you removed hence making the 2nd-4th lines of the code irrelevant. i would still like to keep that functionality so i can modify the title headers in line 2 and 3

Comment: i've adjusted your code to fit with my code, so it works. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by title header, the `h2` 'DATA TITLE' is specified in your `BEGIN` block where you could change it dynamically by reading whatever file field was relevant. The two conditional block in my example output exactly the equivalent of your initial  'conversion' script (except for the addition of the class to the second data column for data rows). Anything you want to do specifically  to the header can be added to the `NR==1` pattern block, and any further processing relevant to the data rows gets added to the `NR>1` block. Glad if it was some help anyway.

Comment: sorry, i meant the table header which is referenced in line 2 and 3.

your code picks up whatever table header is on the csv file, but i wanted to keep the flexibility of adjusting the table header during conversion in line 2 `h[1] = "name"` and line 3 `h[2] = "age"` .

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. You would simply change the print string in the `NR==1` pattern block to `"\n<tr>\n  <th>"h[1]"</th>\n  <th>"h[2]"</th>\n</tr>\n"}`.

Comment: oh. thanks.. then that makes it easier. i appreciate

Comment: Awk is very versatile, and often simple. It can even execute shell commands within the awk block such as extracting other file contents to print. This can be useful for things like your html page head, which could be stored in a separate file and read into awk with `cat`. That allows all the print lines in your BEGIN block to be replaced with a single line: `system("cat path/to/htmlheadtemplate.txt")`. That way quite complex html pages can be built where constant parts are stored in external files, leaving the script to concentrate on forming markup from data files.

Comment: pls, I have a question.  what if i have a third column ```h[3]```. how would i modify this line ```{colorclass= ($2>100 ? "high" : "normal")}``` so the same condition works for the 3rd column. i was playing around with it and couldn't seem to figure it out

Comment: just change the $2 for $3. $variables are *field numbers*. Because your input file has comma-separated values (.csv), I used `FS=","` in the awk BEGIN block to set the *field-separator* (`FS`) to be a comma. Awk then processes each line with anything before the first comma being set to $1 (field 1), anything between the 1st and 2nd comma to $2 (field 2), between the 2nd and 3rd to $3 (field 3) and so on. If you add a new column, its value in each line will be referenced by $3.

Comment: oh yes, i get that. what i meant is, i'd like ```{colorclass= ($2>100 ? "high" : "normal")}``` to process field $2 and field $3 so that the values in column 2 and also column 3 follows the condition

Comment: If **both** the second and third field values have to be higher than 100 for the class to be applied, you combine tests for them using the AND operator `&&` line this: `colorclass= (($2>100 && $3>100) ? "high" : "normal")`. If they're to be applied independently, you'd need to add a different placeholder name (different to 'colorclass') to the td tag for the third column and test it separately: `colorclass = ($2>100 ? "high" : "normal"); othercolorclass = ($3>100 ? "high" : "normal")`.

Comment: what if i wanted to also create a file if the colorclass is greater than 100. for example, if $2>100 then ``system("touch file.txt")``. How would i implement that? Thanks